# Prepare(), execute() Not Working

Tags: php, sql, pdo, execute, prepare

When i tried execute Statement after prepare there is No thing updated.

PHP Code:

```
if ($action == 'update' ) {
echo "<h2 class='text-center'>Update Member</h2>";
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $userid      = $_POST['userid'];
    $username    = $_POST['username'];
    $pass    = $_POST['password'];
    $md5pass = md5($pass);
```

The prepare start Here

```
    //Update REcords
    $stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE users SET UserName = ? WHERE UserID = ? ");
    $stmt->execute(array($username, $userid));

    if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
        echo "User Data has been updated.";
     }
```

PDO sql connection :

```
<?php
$dsn  = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=kdz';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$option = array(
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8',
);

try {

    $con = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $option);
    $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

}

catch(PDOException $e){
    echo 'Faild To Connect'. $e->getMessage();
}
```

?>

Can Professional fix it?

Comment: Professionals will advise you to use `errorInfo()` function

Comment: professionals would also advise not to use md5 for passwords

Comment: Either there is an error **or there is nothing to update** as the value is already the same